# Saving JMeter results in JTL/XML format

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'd like JMeter to save requests/responses to XML file ONLY if the request failed. All passed request should not be logged. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In order to store response data for failed requests all you need is just to add the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
```

In regards to saving requests, I'm afraid you have only 2 choices:

1. save all requests (no matter of pass/fail status)
2. save nothing

Theoretically it can be worked around using scripting-enabled test elements like [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) in combination with [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) or patching JMeter source code, but there is no out-the-box flag to trigger conditional storing of request data.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties types and ways of setting/overriding them